# What is the difference between Google's Contacts API and CardDav API?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, difference, carddav

I understand that they are implemented differently, but what is the difference in terms of functionality?

Comment: Well, for one, if you use CardDAV - being an Internet standard - you can access other services instead of just Google's ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google CardDAV API lets you access the Google contacts API using [CardDAV protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDAV).

> vCard Extensions to WebDAV (CardDAV) is an address book client/server
>   protocol designed to allow users to access and share contact data on a
>   server.

The Google contacts API is itself a Google Data API protocol.

> [GData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GData) (Google Data Protocol) provides a simple protocol for reading
>   and writing data on the Internet, designed by Google. GData combines
>   common XML-based syndication formats (Atom and RSS) with a
>   feed-publishing system based on the Atom Publishing Protocol, plus
>   some extensions for handling queries. It relies on XML or JSON as a
>   data format.

What is a protocol:

> [protocol](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/protocol) In information technology, a protocol is the special set
>   of rules that end points in a telecommunication connection use when
>   they communicate. Protocols specify interactions between the
>   communicating entities.

**What is the difference between Google's Contacts API and CardDav API?**

The difference is the protocol used to access the data.